# Phase portrait with one eigenvalue equal to zero?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In my differential equations classes this semester we have been learning how to sketch phase portraits given a solution to a system of equations including eigenvalues and eigenvectors. The cases we have learnt are

- Real and distinct eigenvalues (nodal sink, source or saddle depending on signs)
- Repeated eigenvalues (proper or improper node depending on the number
  of eigenvectors)
- Purely complex (ellipses)
- And complex with a real part (spiral)

So you can see they haven't taught us about zero eigenvalues. But I'd like to know what the general form of the phase portrait would look like in the case that there was a zero eigenvalue. Is the a general case like the above? If so, what is it?

Comment: In this case the phase portrait is degenarate ( the determinant of the coeffcinet matrix is null). You can see some example here: http://people.math.gatech.edu/~xchen/teach/ode/PhasePortrait-degen.pdf

Comment: @EmilioNovati would we say that the phase portrait is a "comb"?

Comment: Yes, I suppose that this english word can be a good  description. But I don't know if it is the official name :)

Comment: Are you talking about only linear systems or not?

Comment: @Evgeny yes just linear systems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If one eigenvalue is zero than the matrix of the coefficients $A$ has null determinat and a nontrivial null space, and any vector of the null space is an equilibrium point ( stable or unstable depending on the sign of the other eigenvalue). See [here](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~xchen/teach/ode/PhasePortrait-degen.pdf) for some simple example.